Ignore the .NET System.Object inheritance when generating Docfx documentation
I recently tried to use Docfx to document an ongoing project that uses .NET 7.
Everything seems to work fine with the simple commands :
docfx init
docfx myProject\docfx.json --serve

But I did notice that all my custom classes that Docfx generated .md files for show all the information about inheriting from System.Object class.

This can be found in the .yml files as :
  inheritance:
  - System.Object
  inheritedMembers:
  - System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
  - System.Object.Equals(System.Object,System.Object)
  - System.Object.GetHashCode
  - System.Object.GetType
  - System.Object.MemberwiseClone
  - System.Object.ReferenceEquals(System.Object,System.Object)
  - System.Object.ToString

I am aware that all classes inherit from this in .NET, but for this exact reason this is irrelevant information to show in such a graphical documentation.
I tried adding a filterConfig.yml file to the build that contains the following:
### YamlMime:ManagedReference
apiRules:
- exclude:
  uidRegex: ^System\..*
- exclude:
  uidRegex: ^Microsoft\..*

And referenced in my docfx.json like so :
"metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "src": "../myProjectFile",
          "files": [
            "**/*.csproj"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api",
      "filter": "filterConfig.yml"
    }
  ]

Additionally I added this regular expression in the same docfx.json :
"apiFilter": {
      "exclude": {
        "uidRegex": ["^System\\.Object"]
      }
    }

None  of the above changes got rid of the  inheritance.
Is it even possible to not show it?
Would writing a custom docfx post-build script that removes this info from the .yml files be the only way ?
